# How to check whether a geopoint belongs to a certain city using some web services?

Tags: google-maps, reverse-geocoding

Given:

- A city
- A geopoint

Question: determine whether the given geopoint belongs to the city.

My current solution is trivial:

1. Do reverse geocoding (I am using the python [googlemaps](http://py-googlemaps.sourceforge.net/) package). This yields the **results** dictionary.
2. Examine **results['Placemark'][0]['AddressDetails']** looking for the **LocalityName** keyword.
3. The given geopoint is deemed inside the city, if the found **LocalityName** equals the name of the city.

So far so good. Even if it is not the best of algorithms, it is surely the simplest. However, there are problems. Take for instance:

- Aberdeen, UK.
- lat = 57.14369, lng = -2.22314

The `GoogleMaps.reverse_geocode(57.14369, -2.22314)` yields the following result:

```
{ u'Placemark': [ { u'AddressDetails': { u'Accuracy': 6,
                                         u'Country': { u'CountryName': u'UK',
                                                       u'CountryNameCode': u'GB',
                                                       u'Thoroughfare': { u'ThoroughfareName': u'A944'}}},
                    u'ExtendedData': { u'LatLonBox': { u'east': -2.2200414,
                                                       u'north': 57.1480762,
                                                       u'south': 57.1453783,
                                                       u'west': -2.2239393}},
                    u'Point': { u'coordinates': [-2.221984, 57.1467683, 0]},
                    u'address': u'A944, Aberdeen, Aberdeen City AB15, UK',
                    u'id': u'p1'}],
  u'_id': 7635459717214061L,
  u'loc': [-2.2231, 57.1437]}
```

The problem is that the formatted address (`A944, Aberdeen, Aberdeen City AB15, UK`) is not broken into details - the returned `AddressDetails` is essentially useless.

So, it looks like one has to parse the returned `address` manually, which seems to be a real PITA in a general case.

I would like to know how other folks solve this problem. Using the google maps web services API is not a requirement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reverse geocoding **web service** for
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=57.14369,-2.22314&sensor=false

yields far more data than you have posted from the Python package, including

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "A944",
               "short_name" : "A944",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Aberdeen City",
               "short_name" : "Aberdeen City",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
...
```

which seems to fit the bill. You get "Aberdeen City".

Comment: Well, I haven't invented it. This is what googlemaps python package returns. It doesn't invent it either. I can attach the respective HTTP request and response. I will try to use the json endpoint as per your suggestion.

Comment: @mark: I didn't mean to imply you had simply invented it, rather that the Python package didn't return everything you could get using the webservice. Sorry: I should have made that clearer.

Comment: The python package returns everything it gets in the response - I have checked it already. No information is withheld. I think that there are two endpoints for the service and the python googlemaps utilizes the old one.